# undefined method `+@' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake

I wrote this task to populate a table. The "Flight" table is pretty big (23000 posts). But I get this weird error when we move through the loop the second time.

Here's the code:

```
desc "Compute the AirlineTerminal Table"
task :populate_airlineterminals => :environment do
    #first delete content
    AirlineTerminal.destroy_all
    allFlights = Flight.all

        #AFTER ONE ITERATION THE ERROR HAPPENS
    allFlights.each do |f|
        atTerminal = AirlineTerminal.where(:airline_id => f.airline_id, :airport_id => f.airport_id, :terminal => f.terminal).first
        if atTerminal.nil?
            atTerminal = AirlineTerminal.new
            atTerminal.airport_id = f.airport_id
            atTerminal.airline_id = f.airline_id
            atTerminal.terminal = f.terminal
        end
        atTerminal.count++

        atTerminal.save #so far so good
    end
end
```

This is what happens when I run the script, after one trip through the loop it crashes.

```
$ rake populate_airlineterminals
rake aborted!
undefined method `+@' for true:TrueClass
```

Comment: Run your rake task with `--trace` option to get the full stacktrace. At least you'll know which line of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: I named a column count. Not very smart as it collides with the .count operator.  Gonna rename and see what happens.

Comment: `renamed_column :airline_terminals, :count, :departure_count`. No difference. It's after looping back from f.save the first time that it crashes.

Comment: running an empty loop works. It's something inside that makes Ruby freak out.

Comment: seems like it is `++` that is spooking it up.

Comment: aaaarghhhh...camelCase in ruby....aaaarghhhhh :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I do not know the error my bet is that

```
atTerminal++
```

is the culprit. As far as I know ++ is not defined in ruby. You have to use

```
atTerminal += 1
```

unless of course you have defined it yourself. Maybe it causes errors while interpreting the code. Try it in irb.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has no ++ or -- operators only += and -=

[Things That Newcomers to Ruby Should Know](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#operators)